# Direct create function while defining the method

Tags: c#, events, printing, delegates

I am trying to create an anonymous method for handling the `PrintPage` event of a `PrintDocument` object.

Here's what I tried:

```
printDocument1.PrintPage += delegate
{
    // define method
}
```

What I want to accomplish is something like this:

```
printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler
    (object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // define method
}
```

What I would like to do is use the `PrintPageEventArgs` argument `e` when the function is called. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Instead of telling us the solution to your problem and asking us how to make it work, why don't you describe the problem you're trying to solve, and we'll see if we can provide you with a working solution.  See also [What is the X Y Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: mean that
PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
printDocument1.PrintPage += delegate
{
define method
}
 usually we can doing this,

but in the method , i want to grab its event e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), as follows:

```
printDocument1.PrintPage += (s, e) =>
{
    // Method code goes here
    // The variable s represents the first parameter, "object sender"
    // The variable e represents the second parameter, "PrintPageEventArgs e"
};
```

This will create an anonymous method using a lambda expression. The `(s, e)` represent the input parameters in the order they appear in the delegate.

If you're using a version of C# prior to 3.0 and thus don't have lambda expressions, you can do this via a delegate, as follows:

```
printDocument1.PrintPage += delegate(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Method code goes here
};
```

Comment: Since you appear to understand what the OP is talking about, can you suggest an edit to the question so that the question makes sense?

Comment: Also, note that, while it does have the correct signature, the resulting anonymous method is not type-compatible with `PrintPageEventHandler`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you please elaborate? Why is it not compatible?

Comment: I said *type* compatible.  That means you're not going to have any of the facilities that would normally be available to you in a PrintPageEventHandler object.

Comment: Granted, it's probably just a delegate anyway, but still.  The reason I linked the X Y post is that there's really no good reason I can think of to do it this way, other than to confuse the poor developer who has to read this code and try to figure out why the OP chose to write it this way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why it's not type compatible. Looking at [the documentation for the `PrintPage` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.PrintPage%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) it appears to use the same signature, and it should work just fine. I've implemented anonymous event handlers like this in the past, as long as the method code is short and simple, i.e. a line or two. Anything more would be too unwieldy.

Comment: sorry for asking this question because i am .net 2.0 developer, i know lambda can solve my problem but i dont know how to use it since 2.0 seem dont have lambda. i also wish to explorer more so i can know more about lambda and linkq

Comment: I've updated my response to include a solution for .Net 2.0, if you want. You can check out DotNetPerls for a [nice starter tutorial on lambda expressions](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda).